# Attach a callback with regex selector

Tags: jquery

I need to attach a callback only to selects whose id contains a number, I have tried to use [regex selector for jQuery](https://j11y.io/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/), but had no success.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', $r_);
```

I tried:

```
$(document).on('change', $('select:regex(id,[0-9])');, $r_);
```

I have included this on the beginning of my `<script>` tag:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use delegation, you don't wrap `$()` around the selector argument. It should just be

```
$(document).on('change', 'select:regex(id,[0-9])', $r_);
```